# What defines a method as idempotent in Weblogic?

Tags: java, apache, weblogic, weblogic12c

We are using Apache to call weblogic services (a SOAP WebService). We are using the Apache weblogic HTTP plugin. The calls is not retried if the maximum time is being reached.

1. Using SOAP-UI to call the service via Apache
2. In my webservice method I simulate a sleep of 1300ms
3. The WLIOTimeoutSecs setting in my httpd.conf file is set to 10 seconds

SOAP-UI returns me the following error

> Failure of server APACHE bridge:
>
> ---
>
> No backend server available for connection: timed out after 5 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.

I am not sure if the 5 seconds is a default message as I can clearly see that SOAP UI responds within 10003ms. So it clearly uses by 10 second timeout that I specified.

The question is how do you tell the plugin which service methods are idempotent? Idempotent is set to ON. The retry count calculates to 5 times ( ConnectTimeoutSecs/ConnectRetrySecs aka 5/1 = Retry 5 times)

My Full Weblogic Apache plugin config:

```
Listen *:7001
NameVirtualHost *:7001
<VirtualHost *:7001>
    KeepAlive ON
    LogLevel debug
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

    #Enables pooling of connections - Will keep connection open between PlugIn and weblogic server for 60 seconds
    KeepAliveEnabled ON
    #Default=20
    KeepAliveSecs 60

    #Default=ON - When IO timeout occurs and this is set to on it will connect to another server in the dynamic list
    #Needs this setting before a failover will occur and the list to be updated.
    Idempotent ON
    #Default=10 - Will wait 5 seconds before a BAD server is retried again
    MaxSkipTime 30

    #Default=10 - Maximum time taken to obtain a response to a client request
    ConnectTimeoutSecs 5
    #Default=2 - Wait 1 second before attempting to connect (Sleep time)
    ConnectRetrySecs 1
    #MaxRetry-ies = Interval in seconds that the plugin should sleep between attempts to connect to the WLS
    #Based off ConnectTimeoutSecs/ConnectRetrySecs aka 5/1 = Retry 5 times

    #Default=2 (Must be > 0) - Timeout after 2 seconds if we cannot establish a connection
    WLSocketTimeoutSecs 2
    #Default=300 - Time is takes for the weblogic server to respond before the connection fails over to another server
    #Customize this based on logic aka will be overridden on URL level
    WLIOTimeoutSecs 300

    #Used to query based on the ?__WebLogicBridgeConfig  parameter
    DebugConfigInfo ON
    #Will pass the header of the request to pass through the apache server
    #Default=OFF
    WLProxyPassThrough ON
    #Tells the plugin which requests to retry should the connection be lost
    #Default=ALL
    WLRetryAfterDroppedConnection ALL
    #This controls whether a 503 error is returned or a failover initialized
    #Default=ON
    WLServerInitiatedFailover ON        

    <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>                

            <Location /mySuperDuperUrl/>
                    Idempotent ON
                    WLIOTimeoutSecs 10
                    SetHandler weblogic-handler
                    WLSRequest On                        
                    WebLogicCluster server1:123,server2:124,server3:125
            </Location>
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Why not just Increase the ConnectTimeoutSecs to something higher than 5 seconds and make sure all the servers in the backend cluster respond. Idempotent does not apply to services, applies to servers, if it is set to off, a failed request from a server does not get failedover to the other members.

Comment: We have issues with the plugin where by it doesn't seem to connect to the back end servers. Our monitoring application shows the request on apache is taking like 50s while the server responds within 400ms. Right now I have no idea how to debug this to see where the extra time is coming from. Hence if the problem to establish the connection to the back end server. I would want if a connection cannot be obtained or if the server is under strain to rather try another server instead.